# How i can get Contact Number

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

If customer enter un support pincode admin will get mail ther How i can get Contact Number

```
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){        
        $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();


        /* Get Information For Mail */
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

        $name = $customer->getName();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $productName = array();
        /*$skus = array();*/
            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $productName[] = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                /*$skus[] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();*/
            }       
        $productNames = implode(', ', $productName);
        /*$productSkus = implode(', ', $skus);*/

        /* Get Information For Mail */

        $restrictedCodes = array(




    110001,
    110002,
); //restricted values. they can come from anywhere
    if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) { 
 $template_id = 'my_custom_email';
    // Who were sending to...
    $email_to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
    $customer_name   = $name;
    // Load our template by template_id
    $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);

    $custom_variable = $name;
    $custom_variable1 = $email;
    $custom_variable2 = $postCode;
    $custom_variable3 = $productNames;


    // Here is where we can define custom variables to go in our email template!
    $email_template_variables = array(
        'custom_variable' => $custom_variable,
        'custom_variable1' => $custom_variable1,
        'custom_variable2' => $custom_variable2,
        'custom_variable3' => $custom_variable3,
        'custom_variable4' => $custom_variable4,
        // Other variables for our email template.
    );

    // In my case I am using the Store Name as sender name here.
    $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
    // In my case I am using the general store contact here as the sender email.
    $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
    $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 

    //Send the email!
    $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);

    /* Send Mail to admin If Customer try to place order with unsupport Pincode*/
         return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get this from quote session

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
 $billAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();

 Mage::log($billAddress->getData());
  //you can get contact number in that
 $billAddress->getTelephone();
```